# how to replace the space in string with dash - , but avoid when already dash after space

Tags: javascript

i want to change the title of my items to show in url in javascript , for that i need that spaces should be changed to dash - but some of my titles already have - so if it already have then avoid the dash
e.g
here is my title its a string

```
2008 - 2009 PEUGEOT
```

i want it like this

```
2008-2009-PEUGOT
```

Comment: What have you already tried and what issues did you have?

Answer (score 1):

`string.replace(" - ", "-").replace(" ", "-")`

Will first replace any instance of `space-space` with `-`, then any instance of `space` with `-`

Comment: this is not working 
i try this on this string
 2019 - 2020 LEXUS HYBRID UX200 SMART KEY - 4B - 315MHZ - 8990H-76040
and it return me this
2019-2020-Lexus HYBRID UX200 Smart Key - 4B - 315mhz - 8990H-76040

Comment: its just changing first dashes not in all strings

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more robust solution, which works despite how much white space there is or how many dashes there are, you can use the following code:

```js
string.replace(/( *- *)+/g, '-').replace(/ +/g, '-');
```

This matches dashes with any amount of space around them and replaces them with just a dash.

It then matches any leftover white space and replaces it with a dash.

### Working Example

```js
let strings = [
  '2008 - 2009 PEUGEOT',
  '2008     -   2009   PEUGEOT',
  '2008-    2009  -PEUGEOT',
  '2008   --  2009--  -    ---PEUGEOT',
  '2008 --   --- 2009 - -     ---- - PEUGEOT',
  '2008-2009-PEUGEOT'
];

strings.forEach(string => {
  const result = string.replace(/( *- *)+/g, '-').replace(/ +/g, '-');
  console.log(result);
});
```

## EDIT

I have created multiple other solutions, which seem to work at relatively the same speed. **A benchmark is available at [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/insert-dashes/1)**.

```js
string.replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
```

```js
string.replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');
```

```js
string.replace(/ +/g, '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
```

```js
string.replace(/ +/g, '-').replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the regex it can handle more than one whitespace in front or back of - too:

```
(?<!([-\s]))\s+(?!(\s*[-$]))
```

to find all whitespaces that need to be replaced with -
after that you can remove all other whitespaces with

```
string.replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

have to make change in all strings , above answers just making replace in first found dashes and spaces

```
string.replace(/ - /g, "-").replace(/ /g , "-")
```

this works for me